# Bash while loop syntax error in do

Tags: bash, while-loop

I´m trying do do a simple counter:

```
max=100
count=1
while [[ $count -le $max]]
  do
    echo "$count"
    ((count++))
  done
```

This gives me a syntax error in conditional expression near do.

What´s my issue? (probably something obvious)

The idea is then to raise the `max` from 100 to 200 and so forth in a superior loop so I will get a new file to manipulate with a python program 100 lines each time, but that´s irrelevant here.

Comment: see my post, need an extra space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that it need one more space in `[[ $count -le 100]]`

```
max=100
count=1
while [[ $count -le $max ]]
do
    echo "$count"
    ((count++))
done
```

Another solution :

```
while ((count < max+1)); do echo $((count++)); done
```

or

```
for ((i=count; i<max; i++)) { echo $i; }
```

or

```
for ((i=count; i<max; i++)); do echo $i; done
```

or

```
for i in {1..100}; do echo $i; done
```

Comment: Added another `while` solution

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:

```
while [[ $count -le 100]]
```

to:

```
while [[ $count -le 100 ]];
```

Notice the space after 100.

Comment: Semicolon and newline have the same function, i.e. semicolon is not needed here.  This still won't run even with the semicolon.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I know semicolon is optional when there's a newline. But why this won't run?