# Bash while is not working as expected - String comparison

Tags: string, bash, while-loop

I have been stuck for an hour now and still can't figure this out. FYI - I am new to the bash scripting. Here is what I am trying to do

```
var="Y"
while [ "$var" = "Y"]
do
echo "Hello World!!"
echo "Keep going? [Y/N]"
read var
done
```

I am getting an error in the while line (`while [ "$var" = "Y"]`) - I pretty much tried everything - with single `'`, double `"` - no `"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840769/bash-while-loop-syntax-error-in-do

Comment: Did you actually read and try to understand the error given? When I run your script I get: `./script: line 4: [: missing \`]'`. Trying to read the error message can help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a space next to `"Y"`

That is,

```
while [ "$var" = "Y" ]
```